# Решить задачу без использования переменной

Tags: java

В методе generate ссылка на текущий Node сохраняется в переменную ref.

Необходимо решить задачу без использования этой переменной, добавив в цикл for, цикл while.

Исходная задача:

```
public class StringLinkedListTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Node ref = generate(9);
        while (ref != null){
            System.out.print(" " + ref.value);
            ref = ref.next;
        }
    }
    public static Node generate(int max){
        Node result = new Node(max, null);
        Node ref  = result; 
        for (int k = max; k > 0; k--){
            ref.next = new Node(k - 1, null);
            ref = ref.next;
        }
        return result;
    }
} 

public class Node {
    int value;
    Node next;
    public Node(int value, Node next) {
        this.value = value;
        this.next = next;
    }
}
```

Пытаюсь решить, но мой код возвращает `9` вместо `9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0`. Проблема возникает при переходе к вложенным Node.

Подскажите, как здесь можно исправить, чтобы в while осуществлялся переход к следующему Node?

```
public static Node generate(int max){
    Node result = new Node(max, null);
    for (int k = max; k > 0; k--){
        int copy = max;
        while (copy != 0) {
            if (result.next == null){
                result.next = new Node(copy - 1, null);
                break;
            }

            copy--;
        }
        result.next = result.next.next;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Я не вижу никакого смысла в вашей функции generate  с двумя циклами.:)

Answer (score 1):

Вот так должно быть?

```
public static Node generate(int max) {
    int count = 0;
    Node result = null;
    while(max >= count){
        result = new Node(count++, result);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Дополнение к комментарию:

```
public static Node generate(int max) {
    Node result = new Node(max, null);
    for (int k = max; k > 0; k--) {

        Node ref = result;
        while (ref.next != null) {
            ref = ref.next;
        }
        ref.next = new Node(k - 1, null);

    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Не совсем, суть в том, чтобы создание объектов шло в порядке: с value = 8, затем  = 7, и т. д. И при этом нужно обойтись без переменной текущего Node. Т.е. while должен проходить каждый раз по уже созданным объектам, начиная с объекта, у которого value = 9.

Comment: Дополнил ответ как Вы сказали. Но без переменной текущего Node не представляю как это сделать.

Comment: Спасибо болшое. Однако автор курса утверждает, что это возможно сделать в while, который имеет ссылку только на конец, т.е. на result.

Comment: Первый вариант моего ответа так и делает, начинает с конца(т.е. с "0") и возвращает начало связанного списка. Но сделать как в вопросе: `создание объектов в порядке с 8... `,  т.е. не с нуля(с начала) и каждый раз пробегать по списку - это невозможно сделать без дополнительной переменной, либо вопрос поставлен не верно.

Comment: Задача взята отсюда https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=is8w0R6sU58&list=PLoij6udfBnchtjzmTCm5Y372aWrl97AnY&index=6 - время 2:15

Comment: Автор мог ошибиться в постановке такой задачи, попросите его в комментарии к видео написать разъяснение по этому поводу.

Comment: хорошо, большое спасибо за помощь! :)